# How to set secured URL patterns for different file extensions e.g., .xhtml, .jpg, .docx

Tags: spring-security

How can I set secured URL patterns in `AuthorizeExchangeSpec.pathMatchers(String[])`?

I tried setting the pattern but this didn't work.

```
AuthorizeExchangeSpec.pathMatchers(["/cfs/**/*.xhtml", "/cfs/**/*.docx"]).authenticated()
```

The pattern should intercept these URLs:

- `http://www.somedomain.com/cfs/1231asdasd/stage/abc.xhtml`
- `http://www.somedomain.com/cfs/1231asdasd/stage/basket/abc.docx`

Comment: What is `cfs`? Is that your application name?

Comment: yeah thats an application context-root

Comment: Then remove it from your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to solve this issue by writing a custom matcher with AntPathMatcher. 
AuthorizeExchangeSpec has a matchers method in which we can provide our own matcher which extends ServerWebExchangeMatcher

```
AuthorizeExchangeSpec.matchers(ServerWebExchangeMatcher... matchers)
```

And my matcher class is written as below

```
public class CustomMatcherServerWebExchangeMatcher implements ServerWebExchangeMatcher {

private PathMatcher matcher = new AntPathMatcher();

@Override
public Mono<MatchResult> matches(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
    if (this.method != null && !this.method.equals(request.getMethod())) {
        return MatchResult.notMatch();
    }
    String path = request.getPath().pathWithinApplication().value();
    boolean match = matcher.match(pattern, path);

    if (!match) {
        return MatchResult.notMatch();
    }

    Map<String, String> pathVariables = matcher.extractUriTemplateVariables(pattern, path);
    Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<>(pathVariables);
    return MatchResult.match(variables);
}}
```

And here org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher is the class which does all the magic of matching for any file extensions as per this documentation

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html